# Behavior of subquery's where against where of query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could you explain me pls the behavior of where in subquery against where of the query? I have a query

```
SELECT
        [Object_Id]     = S.[Object_Id],
        [Schema]        = S.[Schema],
        [Name]          = S.[Name],
        [Type]          = S.[Type],
       SubString(S.[definition], S.[StartIndex],  S.[EndIndex] - S.[StartIndex]+12),
        S.[definition], S.[StartIndex], S.[EndIndex]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Object_Id]         = P.[object_id],
            [Schema]            = Schema_Name(P.[schema_id]),
            [Name]              = P.[name],
            [Type]              = P.[type],
            [Definition]        = S.[definition],
            [StartIndex]        = X.[StartIndex],
            [EndIndex]          = X.[EndIndex]
        FROM        sys.objects         P
        INNER JOIN  sys.sql_modules     S   ON S.[object_id] = P.[object_id]
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                [StartIndex]     =  CharIndex('<' + 'Generator ', S.[definition]),
                [EndIndex]       =  CharIndex('<'+ '/Generator>', S.[definition])
        ) X
        WHERE  P.[schema_id] <> Schema_Id('SQL')
            and P.[object_id] >= 69665580 --69665579
            and P.[object_id] <= 72985424 --72985424   
            and X.[StartIndex] > 1 
            AND X.[StartIndex] < X.[EndIndex]
    ) S
    WHERE 
        SubString(S.[definition], S.[StartIndex],  S.[EndIndex] - S.[StartIndex]+12) is not null
```

It returns error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function". The problem is recordset of the subquery without 'Where' has records which lead to this error, but with the where clause subquery returns only one correct row. If I insert record form the subquery into a table variable and then use this table in a query it works fine as expeted. But why doesn't it work with subquery? For me it looks like 'Where' of the whole query ignores filters applied to the subquery.

Comment: The WHERE clauses are relative to the SELECT at the same scope, so the WHERE clause in the subquery is for the SELECT in the subquery and the WHERE clause in the outer query is for the SELECT in the outer query.  Your subquery is returning one or more records where `EndIndex - StartIndex + 12` is invalid for the call to `SUBSTRING` in the outer query.

Comment: More than likely I would guess that your calculation S.[EndIndex] - S.[StartIndex] is returning a value less than 12 so when it adds 12 it is negative which will generate that message.

Comment: @squillman subquery 'S' with all its filters returns only one recrod with startindex = 462 and endindex = 511.

Comment: Right, but you said you only get the error when you don't include the WHERE clause in the subquery?

Comment: @squillman, yes error is expeted without where clause but I get error even with where clause. And I don't understand why I get the error if the subquery  with where cluase returns only one correct record.

Comment: What is the value of `definition` in that one row the subquery returns?  Can you create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I would guess that you have a row in the table somewhere that has `</Generator>` before `<Generator>`.  That would end up getting a negative value with your calculation which would pass that negative as the length to substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SQL Server is free to rearrange `WHERE` predicates, including pushing them down into derived tables (subqueries). While it will take calculations into account, it does not take into account possible runtime errors.

Therefore, it's possible that what has happened here is:

- The `CROSS APPLY` calculated values were calulated first.
- The `WHERE  SubString(S.[definition], S.[StartIndex],  S.[EndIndex] - S.[StartIndex]+12) is not null` was applied next.
- Then the other `WHERE P.[schema_id] <> Schema_Id('SQL') and P.[object_id] >= 69665580.....` filters.

There is no way to avoid this happening directly, although using `TOP` and some other operators can often prevent it, but this is not guaranteed. The only way to avoid a runtime error is to null out invalid values using `NULLIF` (which compiles to a `CASE` which is the only guaranteed operator to not be rearranged). You should do this *any* time you use `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX`.

```sql
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                StartIndex     =  NULLIF(CharIndex('<' + 'Generator ', S.definition), 0),
                EndIndex       =  NULLIF(CharIndex('<'+ '/Generator>', S.definition), 0)
        ) X
```

There is one other improvment you should make: avoid `SCHEMANAME` and instead just join `sys.schemas`

```sql
...
[Schema]            = schm.schema_name),
...
INNER JOIN sys.schemas schm ON schm.schema_id = P.schema_id
...
```

Don't quote column names unless you really have to, it's really annoying to read.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Could you give me a link to an official source or a book which describes that behavior please?

Comment: Try this one https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/predicate-ordering-is-not-guaranteed/ba-p/383075 there are also others if you Google